# Dockerfile COPY with @ in path

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Trying to build a nginx docker image, I cannot get around this issue:

```
FROM nginx

COPY node_modules/@company/my-package/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Error:

```
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

`COPY` doesn't get my `@`, without it it works. I tried with `\`, `[]`, `""`, `''`, `\\` without success.

I read it uses golang rules, but couldn't find the solution for `@`.

Thanks!

Comment: Works ok here.  Are you sure the glob actually matches some files?  And that your build context is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an auto-generated `.dockerignore` that had `node_modules` in it. That's why Docker was not finding the source files.

Lesson learned!